# How to make Coroutine work via Game Manager certain state?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Without if statement second script works good. But with "if" coroutine didn't starting. How should i perform check for certain gamestate?

This is part of GameManager script:

```
    public void UpdateGameState(GameState newState)
    {
        State = newState;

        switch (newState)
        {
            case GameState.TapToStart:
                HandleTapTostart();
                break;
            case GameState.MoveToWaypoint:
                break;
            case GameState.ShootAtTargets:
                break;
            case GameState.LoadNextLevel:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(newState), newState, null);
        }

        OnGameStateChanged?.Invoke(newState);
    }

    private void HandleTapTostart()
    {

    }
```

And this is part of other script:

```
 void Awake()
    {
        GameManager.OnGameStateChanged += GameManagerOnGameStateChanged;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        GameManager.OnGameStateChanged -= GameManagerOnGameStateChanged;
    }

    void GameManagerOnGameStateChanged(GameManager.GameState state)
    { 

       //  if (GameManager.Instance.State == GameManager.GameState.TapToStart)
       //  {
             StartCoroutine(PressToStart());
       //  }   

         GameManager.Instance.UpdateGameState(GameManager.GameState.MoveToWaypoint);
    }
```

Comment: The if statement must be evaluating to false, which means your singleton's state must not be equal to `tapToStart`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a State pattern --> https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state

It will easely help you managing your code.